# discord.py bot create_ytdl_player doesn't work

Tags: python, bots, youtube-dl, discord.py

I am pretty new to creating a discord bot (bots generally) and asking questions as well.

I am trying to make it join a channel and play a YouTube song.

I have tried create_ffmpeg_player and start the player and it worked, but when I tried create_ytdl_player() function it doesn't seem to play any music.

I have looked through the entire documentation and examples of people on the web but it seems like I can't make it work.

The bot should enter the music channel by the id and play the song from YouTube.

Here is my code:

```
@client.event
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_ready():
    print('bot is on!')
    channel = client.get_channel('channel id')
    voice = yield from client.join_voice_channel(channel)
    use_avconv = ('use_avconv', False)
    opts = {
            'format': 'webm[abr>0]/bestaudio/best',
            'prefer_ffmpeg': not use_avconv
        }
    player = yield from voice.create_ytdl_player('song url',ytdl_options=opts)
    # ffmpeg player works
    # p = voice.create_ffmpeg_player(player.download_url)
    player.volume = 0.5
    player.start()
    print('playing')
```

> I am getting this:
>
> FFmpeg version SVN-r21566-xuggle-3.4.843, Copyright (c) 2000-2010
>   Fabrice Bellard, et al.   built on Jan 31 2010 09:45:05 with gcc 4.2.4
>
> (TDM-1 for MinGW)
>   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --extra-version=xuggle-3.4.843 --extra-cflags=-I/c/hudson/slave/workspace/xuggle_xuggler_binary_build/jdk/JDK5/label/WindowsXP_i386/build/native/i686-pc-mingw32/captive/usr/local/include
>   --extra-ldflags=-L/c/hudson/slave/workspace/xuggle_xuggler_binary_build/jdk/JDK5/label/WindowsXP_i386/build/native/i686-pc-mingw32/captive/usr/local/lib
>   --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libfaac --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --extra-cflags=-mno-cygwin --extra-cflags=-fno-common --extra-ldflags=-mno-cygwin --extra-ldflags=--out-implib --enable-w32threads --enable-memalign-hack   >libavutil     50. 8. 0 / 50. 8. 0
>
> libavcodec    52.49. 0 / 52.49. 0
>
> libavformat   52.48. 0 / 52.48. 0
>
> libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
>
> libswscale     0. 9.
>   0 /  0. 9. 0

Comment: Inside voice.create_ytdl_player, the first argument should be a legitimate song url. Also, discord.py's rewrite library completely removes this feature, so take that into consideration.

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx I did check it with a legitimate song url but it doesn't work. What rewrite library?  I have seen in the discord.py library an example doing exactly what i did.

Comment: Rapptz rewrote a majority of the code in the new rewrite branch. http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ You are currently using the async branch, which is the old version. You can still use it, but I thought I should bring it to your attention. If ffmpeg works but not ytdl, did you make sure you installed the youtube_dl module?

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx i am using the 0.16v of discord.py and not the updated one (trying to pip install but it doesn't update to the v1.0). Also, i do have youtube_dl installed so i don't really know why it won't work.

Comment: Because rewrite isn't in pip yet. You'd have to use git and install it that way. You should be at 0.16.6 if you're not using rewrite. Regardless, could you please tell me what error you're specifically getting?

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx it doesn't give me any error, it writes the same thing as when i do create_ffmpeg_player but doesn't play the song

Comment: I think you pressed enter prematurely

Comment: Ok, I think your opts are wrong. 'prefer_ffmpeg' should just be a True or False, but you're passing a Tuple. Please try that.

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx i have tried doing :

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx i have tried this:                                                               
player = yield from voice.create_ytdl_player('url',ytdl_options={'prefer_ffmpeg':True}) but it still doesn't seem to work. it only gives me the download_url given by the youtube_dl library

Comment: EDIT: Just try without options and see what happens

Comment: i got this error:
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Discord Bot/main.py", line 32, in on_ready
    player = yield from voice.create_ytdl_player('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ&list=PLqDzNilwDj_dm_BOGxoCRmvA6CheRwAiw',prefer_ffmpeg=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 541, in create_ytdl_player
    player = self.create_ffmpeg_player(download_url, **kwargs)
TypeError: create_ffmpeg_player() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefer_ffmpeg'

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx still doesn't work. It does print out the download_url but doesn't play it like when i use the create_ffmpeg_player()

Comment: Hmm.. Ok. It's really hard to solve your problem without any errors or feedback. You can go to the discord API server, [here](https://discord.gg/0SBTUU1wZTUzBx2q) and ask the people in #discord-py for help